# Statistical Testing of Non-linear Model Parameters

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, nonlinear-regression, nonlinear, f-test

I have produced three non-linear 4-parameter logistic curves based on some experimental observations using three different measurement devices. Each curve shows the measurement of density decline during a laboratory based fermentation. I'd like to be able to demonstrate some form of significance testing between the fits of each of the devices. There is no difference in model complexity betwen fits as I have already determined the best model (in terms of parameterisation) to describe my data.

Most significance testing I have found is based around F-tests ([such as that described by Prism's compare function](https://www.graphpad.com/guides/prism/6/curve-fitting/reg_interpreting_comparison_of_mod.htm)) but I do not believe this is appropriate in this case.

I have seen suggestions that looking at the confidence interval ranges for each parameter would determine significant differences but ideally some form of significance test would be much better.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? What are null hypothesis/alternative you are interested in? If that's too formal a question for you, what exactly do you want to learn? Whether all curves are the same? We don't do significance testing in order to do significance testing, we do it because we want to learn something specific.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My hypotheses are as follows:
H0 - the curves are not different
H1 - the curves are different
So in other words, yes, I'm looking to determine whether the curves are the same, sorry if that wasn't clear in the question

Comment: Are the curves of the same family, only with different parameter values? If so, you could still set this up as nested models problem and use an F-test, by parametrising it appropriately. For example if you have a parameter $a$ and $a_1, a_2, a_3$ for the three curves, you could write them $a, a+q_1, a+q_2$ and the test $q_1=q_2=0$, similar for the other parameters.

Comment: They are as you desribed and that makes sense, would you know if there is an elegant way to set up the form you described in R?

Comment: Probably. I can't do it right now, not only because I don't know how your curves are defined, but also because of other things to do. Not sure enough to say something without checking it on data.